# How to do AUTO-UPDATE ID of Customers when one of them is deleted in REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, crud, api-design

I want to auto-update the ID of each customer in the server hosted in localhost:8080 when one or two customers selected randomly gets deleted. Like if there were 5 customers (A,B,C,D,E) with ID (1,2,3,4,5) respectively, and when C and D get deleted, the IDs of all remaining customers should auto-update to 1,2,3 where the ID of E=3.

```
const express = require ('express');
const Joi = require ('joi');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const customers = [
    {title: 'John', id: 1},
    {title: 'Mark', id: 2},
    {title: 'Nathan', id: 3},
    {title: 'Julian', id: 4},
    {title: 'Clio', id: 5}
]
app.post('/api/customers/', (req, res)=>{

    const {error} = validateCustomer(req.body);
    if(error){
        res.status(404).send(error.details[0].message)
        return;
    }
    const customer = {
        id: customers.length + 1,
        title: req.body.title
    };
    customers.push(customer);
    res.send(customer);
});
app.delete('/api/customers/:id', (req, res)=>{
    const customer = customers.find(c=> c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if(!customer) res.status(404).send('<h2>Does not exist</h2>');

    const index = customers.indexOf(customer);
```

Comment: I (think I) understand what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure why you want to do it. IDs should be immutable, otherwise you could run into all sorts of issues, especially if you have multiple clients of your API. If the ID of a customer has changed between calls for one API client (by another API client deleting a different customer) then they could end up deleting or updating a completely unintended record. If someone deletes a customer `DELETE /customers/3` then a subsequent get to the same ID should return a `404`, not an entirely different customer.

Comment: Hi Johnson. That's a very interesting point you pointed out. But since it is only a learning thing, for now, the admin of the API should have the power the delete customer. Just wanted to see how the IDs can automatically be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ID is not necessarily a good practice.
Treat the value that will change as an index.

```
const customers = [
    {id:1, title: 'John', index: 1},
    {id:2, title: 'Mark', index: 2},
    {id:3, title: 'Nathan', index: 3},
    {id:4, title: 'Julian', index: 4},
    {id:5, title: 'Clio', index: 5}
]

var delete_customers = [3,4];

//The filter will remove customer witch the index is in delete_customers
var new_customers = customers.filter(function(customer){

  return !( delete_customers.includes(customer['index']) );

})
//Using the object index to repopulate the index
.map(function(e,i){
  e['index'] = i + 1;
  return e;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael. Your suggestion noted. However, for this particular practice, I want to put the id(s) of the customers I want to delete in the url, like localhost:8080/api/customers/3 (if I want to delete customer with id=3), and the rest of the id(s) should automatically update their value. Hope that makes sense.